# Relating PHP OOP with Form Registeration For Real World Users

Tags: php, forms, validation, oop

Though I am new to the PHP world, and will like help with this:

After users visits your website and fills out the form, the user proceeds to submission. Once the user clicks on submit (with PHP as the server framework) they expect to be redirected to their page.

Now how do I relate the OOP new object part to the new user for the network? See what I mean in brief:

My OOP side:

```
class  Users {
protected $firstname;
protected $lastname;
protected $password;
protected $email;


public function __construct($firstname, $lastname, $password, $email){
$this->firstname = $firstname;
$this->lastname = $lastname;
$this->password = $firstname;
$this->email = $email;
}

//Some function here...

}

$newuser = new Users();
$anotheruser = new Users();
```

So now after form validation side when the new user must have clicked submit, and he/she expects to go to their page, how do I relate the form validation side with my OOP for the real world process?

In the end, the new user now sees, welcome Mark (as a result of this: $this->firstname) on the other page.

Thank you...

Comment: You could use session variables to forward data from one step to another: _session\_start()_; and _$\_SESSION['firstname'] = $this->firstname;_ where the user is logged in. _session\_start()_; and _echo 'Welcome' . $_SESSION['firstname']_ on the following page.

Comment: Actually this question is too broad, it is like "I have a box of nails, now, how do I build the house?". Anyway, I posted my answer, although it is probably not what you expected to see.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that there are much more things to do here than just define the `User` class.

The general flow for the web app is something like this:

1. User enters his data on the registration form
2. Form is POSTed to your php code
3. You application class routes the POST request to the specific code which handles user registration
4. User data is validated, if something is wrong, the error response is sent back to the browser
5. User data is saved to the database
6. User session is started, so your application knows that he/she is logged in
7. Successful response is sent to the browser (or your code redirect browser to the profile page)

Now, on the code level, there will be many objects.
I assume that your application will have a single entry point, some base `index.php` file which accepts all the requests and then routes to the handlers.

So you will have (this is not a real code, just a structure):

**index.php**

```
$app = new WebApplication();
$app->run();
```

**framework/Application.php**

```
class WebApplication {

   public function run() {
       $request = new Request();  // will parse data from $_GET, $_POST, etc
       $router = new UrlRouter($request);
       $controller = $router->resolveRequest(); // according to the rules you define, it will find
                                                // what controller to create
                                                // controllers handle specific requests
       $controller->run();
   }

}
```

**framework/Controller.php**

```
class Controller {   // You will have a base class for controllers
   // ...
}
```

**application/controllers/UserController.php**

```
class UserController extends Controller {   

   public function actionRegister() {
       // Create user validator and pass the Request object into it
       $validator = UserValidator($this->getRequest());
       if (!$validator->validate()) {
           // render the HTML with error
           $this->render('error', array('message'=>$validator->getError()));
           // OR send as json
           $this->sendJson(array(
               'status'=>'error', 'message'=>$validator->getError()
           ));
       } else {
           $user = new User(
               $this->getRequest()->get('email'),
               $this->getRequest()->get('password')
               // ...
           );
           $dbTable = new UsersTable();
           $dbTable->save($user);
           $this->startSession($user);
   }

}
```

**application/models/User.php**

```
class User extends Model {

    protected $email;
    protected $firstname;
    //... 

    public function __construct($email, $password) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

And so on, we need to define `UserValidator`, `UserTable` and everything else.

So the `User` class in your question is only a small part of the big picture.
If you want to do the OOP properly, you are going to have a lot of classes and objects.
They may be similar to what I describe above or they may differ a lot, but the overall idea will be the same - the features you need should be split over a relatively small objects and you combine them to build your application.

If you want to do this, the best thing is to learn how it is done in popular frameworks. You don't need to dive deep from the start and learn the code, just go through the few tutorials to see how it looks for the framework user.

Comment: Based on your response, which framework would you advice I learn about to help build my application better? There are so many of them, that I don't seem to get a head start with.Thank you.

Comment: @Louis My personal preference is Yii, Laravel also seems to be very popular.